# Win32 application. HBITMAP LoadImage fails to load anything

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, null, loadimage

I'm writing a function that quickly draws an image of a menu for a game I'm making. I'm able to draw the background and text blocks just fine but I'm having trouble creating a bitmap image on the screen

```
bool menu::drawMenu(PAINTSTRUCT ps)
{
HWND hWnd = GetActiveWindow();
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd), hdcMem;

//Draw a new background

HPEN blackPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 0, 0));
HBRUSH blackBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
SelectObject(hdc, blackPen);
SelectObject(hdc, blackBrush);
Rectangle(hdc, 0, 0, 1080, 720);

//insert selection text

TextOut(hdc, 30, 0, L"New Game", 8);
TextOut(hdc, 30, 30, L"Exit Game", 9);

//draw arrow sprite

HBITMAP arrow = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"C:\\Users\\Tim\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\BoulderBisque\\BoulderBisque\\arrow.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
if (arrow == NULL)
{
    TextOut(hdc, 0, 60, L"Image Load Failed", 17);
    return false;
}
hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
if (hdcMem == NULL)
{
    TextOut(hdc, 0, 90, L"Memory Creation Failed", 22);
    return false;
}
SelectObject(hdcMem, arrow);
BitBlt(hdc, 0, choice * 30, 16, 16, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

//cleanup

ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
DeleteDC(hdcMem);

return true;
}
```

As of now arrow is NULL and I get the Load Image Failed textbox.
I am using the relative path of arrow.bmp I also tried using a full path, that didn't work either.

You may have noticed that this function is outside the WndProc. Everything else draws fine.
I tried running it in there too everything but the arrow.bmp loads.

What am I doing wrong to cause arrow.bmp to be NULL? I have other methods I plan to run in similar ways so getting this function to run would really be a big help.

EDIT* Whenever I give the full path name it still fails to load.
Also is this not the appropriate code for SO? This is my first question...

EDIT** The aditional '/'s haven't fixed the issue.

EDIT*** Using GetLastError, I found the error code to be 2, ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Always use the full path of a file.  Always post the right code in an SO question.

Comment: The `GetActiveWindow` call also seems a bit dubious.

Comment: Should be `L"C:\\Users\\Tim\\Documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\BoulderBisque\\BoulderBisque\\arrow.bmp"` with more `\\` things.

Comment: Write a small console test program that does nothing but attempt to load the imnage.

Comment: You have to read the documentation carefully. When `LoadImage` returns `NULL`, you find out more by calling `GetLastError`. It's written as clear as can be in the documentation. You simply must read the docs. So, call `GetLastError` to find out more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your early versions of the question checked the return value of `LoadImage` but then did nothing more. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045.aspx) says this:

> If the function fails, the return value is `NULL`. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

So, if the function fails, call `GetLastError` to find out why. When you do so, you obtain the error code `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. Which is pretty conclusive. The filename that you specified does not exist.

Do note that the code in the latest update to the question calls `GetLastError` unconditionally. That is a mistake, one that is seen all too frequently here on Stack Overflow. The documentation only tells you to call `GetLastError` when the call to `LoadImage` fails. If the call to `LoadImage` succeeds, then the value return by `GetLastError` is meaningless. Error handling in Win32 is largely handled in the same way as `LoadImage` does it, but not always. So you have to read the documentation very carefully.

---

Perhaps instead of

```
C:\\Users\\Tim\documents\\...
```

you meant

```
C:\\Users\\Tim\\documents\\...
```

---

OK, now you've got the path right. The call to `LoadImage` returns `NULL`, but `GetLastError` is no longer helpful and returns `ERROR_SUCCESS`. Which is weird in itself.

I believe that the problem is that your image uses a format that `LoadImage` does not understand. I took your .bmp file, loaded it in Paint.net and then re-saved it. Once I did that, the re-saved image was loaded successfully.

---

Rather than trying to load this from a file it would make far more sense to link the image as a resource and load it that way.

Comment: There must be a problem with my file path because the file I'm trying to use does exist. I'm sure it's spelled correctly. I included it in the resources on Visual Studio to get the exact path. So if the path is
C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BoulderBisque\BoulderBisque\arrow.bmp

and the relative path is just
arrow.bmp
what should that second argument be?

Comment: Okay so when I edited that one '\' in the GetLastError is now 0 which means it succeeds but arrow is still NULL so it still failed, when I run it through the debugger it says that arrow is NULL because <Unable to read memory>

As for calling GetLastError unconditionally, I'll think of something more clever to do with it after I sort this issue out.

Comment: I think I answered the question. The code returned NULL. I told you how to call GetLastError. I told you what the error meant. I found the error in your filename. I don't believe you that the function returns NULL and GetLastError is 0.

Comment: Here is what I see in the debugger http://puu.sh/5Mond.png
And here is the output window http://puu.sh/5Moos.png

Comment: Well, that's very strange indeed. Can you put the bmp on a file share site please?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/CzNg7zu.png
That's not right though, it should be a small blue arrow, but when uploaded it's blank.
I also uploaded it to mediafire http://www.mediafire.com/download/fsibq2i1avhp9q3/arrow.bmp

Comment: The image format is not recognised by `LoadImage`. See my latest update.

Comment: Well there it is, a beautiful 16x16 image and no failures.
Hey I appreciate all your help on this. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks for the accept. My strong advice here is to add it as a resource and avoid trying to deploy the image files alongside the executable

Comment: I also encountered a similar problem. LoadImage returned NULL but GetLastError returned success (0). I re-saved the image as advised here and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: What a true legend! The "open paint and resaved the image" worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found through experimenting with Gimp, that your .bmp file must have the following attributes in order for it to work:

1. `depth:24bit`
2. "Do not show write color space information" box checked: [Gimp export options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scypg.png)

If that still doesn't work then try to "unblock" it: [File options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcRR0.png).