# How do I load a bitmap into a Win32 application?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to load a bitmap in a Win32 application, but for some strange reason the bitmap does not load. Here is what I have so far:

```
HANDLE hImg = LoadImageW(
    NULL,
    L"img.bmp",
    IMAGE_BITMAP,
    0,
    0,
    LR_LOADFROMFILE
);
if (hImg == NULL) {
    std::cout << GetLastError();
}
```

Compiled on GCC 8.1.0 with `-Wall -municode`.

Nothing is output to the console, so there are no errors. However, the image never shows up. These questions seem to address a similar issue, but I have had a look at them and couldn't find a solution:

- [I cannot load image from folder using win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56753001/i-cannot-load-image-from-folder-using-win32)
- [Win32 application. HBITMAP LoadImage fails to load anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584045/win32-application-hbitmap-loadimage-fails-to-load-anything)

Where could the problem be?

Full code:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = {};

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        CLASS_NAME,
        L"My Application",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    HANDLE hImg = LoadImageW(
        NULL,
        L"img.bmp",
        IMAGE_BITMAP,
        0,
        0,
        LR_LOADFROMFILE
    );
    if (hImg == NULL) {
        std::cout << GetLastError();
    }

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;

        case WM_PAINT: {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?

Comment: To load a bitmap.

Comment: Do you have some viewing code somewhere? Maybe the bug is in how you are viewing it

Comment: @GSerg but on my PC it doesn't.

Comment: It's not supposed to show the image.

Comment: @drescherjm what do you mean by viewing code?

Comment: I mean code that shows the image in some window. Loading an image just loads the bitmap. It does not show it anywhere.

Comment: @drescherjm I added the full code. Can you point out what is wrong?

Comment: @GSerg how did you conclude it's a console app? It has both a GUI and a console.

Comment: @WaisKamal From the `std::cout << GetLastError()` and the "Nothing is output to the console".

Comment: `std::cout` prints to the console and can be used in both GUI and console applications (I am not compiling with `-mwindows`).

Comment: It's a complete mystery to me what you hope the code would do. Apparently it successfully loads the image, but then you decide not to do anything with that image, and come up with completely contrived conclusions. There used to be a time when it was required for askers to demonstrate familiarity with the problem domain to prevent getting questions that aren't useful to anyone.

Comment: How do I display the image? Can you point out any references showing how to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the window procedure to do all the drawing in `WM_PAINT`. Once the image is loaded successfully, create a memory DC, select the bitmap into the memory DC, and draw the memory DC onto the target window DC.

When the bitmap handle from `LoadImage` is no longer needed, it should be deleted `DeleteObject` (or `DestroyCursor`/`DestroyIcon` depending on what resource was loaded)

```
HANDLE hImg = NULL;
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    switch (uMsg) 
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        if (!hImg)
            hImg = LoadImage(NULL, L"img.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        if (!hImg) { DWORD err = GetLastError(); std::cout << err; }
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT: 
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));

        if (hImg) {
            BITMAP bm;
            GetObject(hImg, sizeof(bm), &bm);//get bitmap dimension
            auto memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            auto oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, (HBITMAP)hImg);
            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);//restore memdc
            DeleteDC(memdc);//delete memdc, we don't need it anymore
        }

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        if (hImg) DeleteObject(hImg);//release resource
        hImg = NULL;
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

When using `GetLastError`, make sure the function is called immediately after failure. Example:

```
if (hImg == NULL) 
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    std::cout << err << '\n';
}
```

If `UNICODE` is already defined, we can use `LoadImage` instead of `LoadImageW`

Comment: And thus `hImg` is leaked.

Comment: @GSerg Fair point, updated.

Comment: By the way, also add `wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);` in `wWinMain`

Answer (score 4):

You are merely loading the bitmap into memory, but you are not actually displaying it anywhere. You need to either:

- create a child [`STATIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/static-controls) control on your window, giving it the `SS_BITMAP` window style, and then send it a [`STM_SETIMAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/stm-setimage) message.
- have your window's `WM_PAINT` message handler select the bitmap into an in-memory `HDC` using [`CreateCompatibleDC()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatibledc) and [`SelectObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectobject), and then copy that `HDC` onto your window's `HDC` (returned by `BeginPaint()`) using [`BitBlt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt) or [`StretchBlt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt).